# Is there a way to run multiple spring boot context at the same time for integration test?

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot

I have many test class In my application. I use liquibase to create my database and dbunit to insert data. I use testng suit to run all test. The trouble comes when I active multithreading to run all classes together.

I want to run all test class in multithreading and each test class must have it's contexte and it's database.

I tried to create multiple spring-datasource.xml where I give the information of the database to use. So each test class has it's datasource config.

Here is the head of my test classes.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "/config/datasource/Spring-Datasource2.xml",
    })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
```